# ffmpeg crashes when extracting PNG's from video

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, windows-10, 64-bit, png

I am attempting to extract PNG's from a video (.avi) using ffmpeg. My code is:

```
    ffmpeg -i vidx.avi -f image2 imgx_%d.png
```

Normally that would work fine, but just now it has been causing ffmpeg to crash, a box appears telling me 'ffmpeg.exe has stopped working .. etc...', however changing from png's to jpeg's and the problem goes away.

The format of the video doesn't seem to matter, an mp4 and mpg also have the same issue as the avi.

This has only just happened (in the past day) on a Windows 10(x64)PC so, could it be related to a MS/Windows Update.. is that possible? Does anyone know what else could cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at recently installed programs, realised I'd installed ImageMagick, which has a command-line interface and the Environmental Variable, which was automatically set, is for the folder that not only includes the "magick.exe" but also an "ffmpeg.exe" (version 3.4), and as this was on the Environmental Variables list first, Windows assumed *that* was the version to use, and not the standalone version that I normally use (a nightly-build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).
So just moving the standalone version above the ImageMagick entry did the trick.